# Capybara assert read only field

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the following html snippet that I'm trying to test:

```
<input type="text" value="Pool A" name="name" class="form-control form-control-1-2" required="" readonly="" style="background-color: rgb(222, 224, 226);">
```

I can see that the element is set to readonly.  I'd have preferred disabled but there we go!!

Is there a way I can assert that input field as readonly using Capybara?

I've come across `readonly: true` in some documentation so I tried:

`expect(page).to have_css('name', readonly: true)`

But it fails to say that `readonly` is not a valid option.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I’m not familiar with that attribute, but with most html attributes like that, an empty string means it’s not applied — so you might need to specify it as `readonly="readonly"` or such.

Comment: It's a new attribute to me as well.  On screen it appears to behave the same as disabled.

Comment: @GrantNeufeld The `readonly` attribute has been supported by most browsers since v1.0 on `input` and `textarea` elements. It is a boolean attribute, which means the attribute presence (no matter the value) indicates readonly behavior for the field and to have non-readonly behavior you need to completely remove the attribute.  The benefit of readonly over disabled is that readonly fields get submitted with the form, disabled fields don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any selector type (:field, etc) you can pass to `find` you can also pass to `have_selector`.  Since the `:field` selector type takes the name/id/associated label text as its first parameter, the cleanest way of checking that a page has a readonly field with 'name' as either the id, name, or label text is

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:field, 'name', readonly: true)
```

which can be written more succinctly as

```
expect(page).to have_field('name', readonly: true)
```

Comment: I got ```nvalid keys :readonly, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :id, :class, :visible, :exact, :exact_text, :normalize_ws, :match, :wait, :filter_set (ArgumentError)``` with `have_selector`

Comment: @ubugnu With what type of selector? The `:field` option in the example above is important because it identifies the type of thing being looked for and enables options specific to that type of element.  Without specifying a selector type you'd be using a selector type of :css, which doesn't support a `readonly` option because not all of the element types it returns support the concept of readonly/editable

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I confirm that it works with find_field

Comment: @ubugnu Yes - it will work with `find_field`, it will also work with `have_field`, and with `have_selector(:field, ...)` since that's how `have_field` is actually implemented - basically the :readonly option is available on anything that uses the `:field` selector type - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Selector

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Ah! I think I used a selector `*[formcontrolname=name]` with `have_selector`, that's why it didn't work. Perhaps using `input[formcontrolname=name]` would have been better

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this

```
expect(page).to have_selector("input[name='name'][readonly='']")
```

**edit**

You are right. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's not valid CSS - the correct CSS to do that would be `input[name='name'][readonly='']`

Answer (score -1):

Upon doing some deeper searching, I found a boolean option.  You can ask if it's read only.

When it is, it results in true, when the read only attribute is not there (indicating a visible field to interact with, it will return nil).

I've written the following assertions for now.

```
expect(find(:field, type: 'text', name: 'name').readonly?).to be true
```

or

```
expect(find(:field, type: 'text', name: 'name').readonly?).to be nil
```

when blank

Thank you for your repsonses.

Comment: This is not a good solution and will end up with flaky tests if the element is changing from non-readonly to readonly while you're  testing. A good rule of thumb is to only use Capybara provided matchers when dealing with content/attributes of Capybara returned elements (no `eq`,  `be`, etc).  If you do have to check an attribute which a Capybara selector type doesn't support (the :field type does support `readonly`) then you should check it in a filter block passed to a Capybara matcher.